# How to find integer representing code point of special character? TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding, ord

I want to calculate integer represeting code point of few domestic characters in different encodings (I'm sure all those codecs include those characters.). My program looks like this:

```
characters = ['Č', 'č', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž']
codecs = ['iso8859_2', 'cp1250', 'mac_latin2', 'utf-8', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_16_be']

for letter in characters:
    for code in codecs:
        print(letter + ' ' + code + ' ' + str(ord(letter.encode(code))))
```

Output:

```
Č iso8859_2 200
Č cp1250 200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Miha/Documents/2Semester/IK/Vaja2/chrEncode.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(letter + ' ' + code + ' ' + str(ord(letter.encode(code))))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
Č mac_latin2 137
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found classmethod `int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder, *, signed=False)` which does the job instead of `ord()`.
Code:

```
characters = ['Č', 'č', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž']
codecs = ['cp852', 'iso8859_2', 'cp1250', 'mac_latin2', 'utf-8', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_16_be']

for letter in characters:
    for codec in codecs:
        decCodePoint = int.from_bytes(letter.encode(codec), byteorder='big') #code point integer
        print(letter + ' ' + codec + ' ' + str(decCodePoint) + ' ' + str(hex(decCodePoint)) + ' ' + str(oct(decCodePoint))) #i also convert decimal integer to hexadecimal and octal
```

Output only for 'Č':

```
Č cp852 172 0xac 0o254
Č iso8859_2 200 0xc8 0o310
Č cp1250 200 0xc8 0o310
Č mac_latin2 137 0x89 0o211
Č utf-8 50316 0xc48c 0o142214
Č utf_16_le 3073 0xc01 0o6001
Č utf_16_be 268 0x10c 0o414
```

Answer (score 0):

Next commented code snippet could help:

```
characters = ['Č'] #, 'č', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž']
codecs = ['iso8859_2', 'cp1250', 'mac_latin2', 'utf-8', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_16_be']

for letter in characters:
    for code in codecs:
        charenc = letter.encode(code)
        if len(charenc) == 1:
            charcod = str(ord(letter.encode(code)))
        else:
            charcod = '0x'   + ''.join('{:02X}'.format(charenc[i]) \
                                    for i in range(0,len(charenc)))
        print(  letter       + 
                ' U+'        + '{:04X}'.format(ord(letter)) + # Unicode codepoint (UCS-2)
                ' (='        + str(ord(letter))             + # detto in decimal
                '), length=' + str(len(charenc))            + # string length
                ' '          + charcod                      + # value
                ' in '       + code                         + # encoding 
                '')
```

**Output**:

```
D:\test\Python> python 37191263.py
Č U+010C (=268), length=1 200 in iso8859_2
Č U+010C (=268), length=1 200 in cp1250
Č U+010C (=268), length=1 137 in mac_latin2
Č U+010C (=268), length=2 0xC48C in utf-8
Č U+010C (=268), length=2 0x0C01 in utf_16_le
Č U+010C (=268), length=2 0x010C in utf_16_be
```

Here all `utf-8`, `utf_16_le` and `utf_16_be` -converted values are printed in hexadecimal but converting them to *decimal* wouldn't be problematic task although decimals seems to be of no use IMHO. On the contrary, I'd convert *all* to hexadecimal in other cases as well.

Sorry if my adaptation of your script looks small. 
It's my first Python meeting as I install and try it not until your question… Thanks for inspiration to a new peculiar experience!

Comment: It worked your way but I think I found simpler solution! Thanks anyway!